# Evaluate each row of UITableView separately iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsarray

I want to show a picture if each row starts with a certain character, let's say "&" in the below example. The code below seems to only work if the first row doesn't start with '&'. If the first row has '&' all of the rows will have the picture. What's wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if ([[[array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)] substringToIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"&"])
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)+1];
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
            return cell;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)+1];
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first `cell` may be reused later on, you have to "reset" its state on every call of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  Try adding `cell.imageView.image = nil` after `cell.detailTextLabel.text` in the `else` block.